# VBScript cannot delete folder "Permission Denied Error"

Tags: vbscript, permissions, directory, folder-permissions

I am using `VBscript` to delete folder recursively. The folders present are `SERVIGISTICS\EDSSolo5.8\`"Several more folders and batch files"....

I am using

```
If oFSO.FolderExists("C:\Program Files\SERVIGISTICS")then
   oFSO.DeleteFolder "C:\Program Files\SERVIGISTICS", True
End if
```

The `oFSO.DeleteFolder` pops out `runtime error "Permission Denied"`
I am running the script in System Context which has full permissions to that directory.
Administrator is the owner of the folder

Comment: This might happen if some program still has an open handle to that folder or something in it. Use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) or [`handle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) to verify.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the folder manually at the same time?

Comment: @omegastripes Yes, manually it is deleting without any problem

Comment: Try to use CMD: `Path = "C:\Program Files\SERVIGISTICS": MsgBox "Return code: " & CreateObject("WSCript.Shell").Run("cmd.exe /c rmdir /s /q """ & Path & """", 0, True)`, or even WMI.

Comment: Thanks a lot...It worked like a charm

Comment: omegastripes' code works provided all VBA references to the folder are released first. That is, you might need to add `ChDir ([some other folder path])` first to make it work, otherwise you might still get the permission denied error.